# Print out int[][] array using streams

Tags: java, arrays, stream

I have a method rotateImage that returns an int[][] array, I am having trouble understaing how to display the actual values of the array instead of just the hashcode:

```
[I@548c4f57
[I@1218025c
[I@816f27d
```

I tried doing this:

```
Arrays.stream(rotateImage(matrix)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

but that only returns the hashcode, not the actual numbers themselves. I also tried using to Arrays.toString() method in several ways but always get an error.

Comment: Try `Arrays.deepToString`

Comment: `Arrays.stream(rotateImage(matrix)).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);`

Answer (score 0):

It's cause you're accessing the address and not the actual values. You can simply do a lambda function and iterate through each row

```
Arrays.stream(rotateImage(matrix)).
         forEach(row -> {
             for(int i : row) {
                System.out.println(i);                 
             }
        });
```